# How can I determine which queues/directories are being processed by SendMail queue runner?

Tags: linux, centos, email, sendmail

I've got a CentOS box running multiple instances of sendmail. Each of those instances have separate queue directories.

As far as I know, I only have a single queuerunner process and I'm not sure if it is aware of all the queues for all the instances.  How can I determine which queues will be monitored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendmail's queue runner will run on the queue directory (or directories, or groups) for which it is configured.  So the answer to your question is "Look in `sendmail.mc` (or `sendmail.cf`) and see which queues each instance is configured to run."

Depending on how your system is set up and what kind of behaviors you need each individual daemon may run its own queue (in which case you would need multiple queue runners), or you may have one sendmail daemon dedicated to nothing but running the queues.

Comment: Thanks.  I checked and each instance has it's own queue directory. For example: **O QueueDirectory=/var/spool/mqueue-foo/example/daemon** in one sendmail.cf and **O QueueDirectory=/var/spool/mqueue-foo/example2/daemon**  in another sendmail.cf.